# Waiting for operation to complete in Swift 3

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I'm trying to use the new `DispatchGroup` mechanism with an `OperationQueue` so that my unit test will wait for completion. After watching the WWDC videos I've only seen how to use groups with async calls from regular dispatches. **How do I get the same functionality with Operation Queues?**

This is my test without any pauses (and therefore it passes without stopping to test assertion in completion block):

```
func testAlertOperationPresentsMessage() {
    var testSuccess = false
    let action: AlertClosure = { action in
        testSuccess = true
    }

    let alert = AlertOperation(title: "Test", message: "Message", context: nil, action: action)

    alert.completionBlock = { XCTAssert(testSuccess) }

    OperationQueue.main.addOperation(alert)
}
```

In previous versions of Swift I would've done something like this:

```
func testAlertOperationPresentsMessage() {
    var testSuccess = false
    let action: AlertClosure = { action in
        testSuccess = true
    }

    let alert = AlertOperation(title: "Test", message: "Message", context: nil, action: action)

    let group = dispatch_group_create()
    dispatch_group_enter(group)
    alert.completionBlock = { dispatch_group_leave(group) }

    OperationQueue.main.addOperation(alert)
    dispatch_group_wait(group, FOREVER...) {
        XCTAssert(testSuccess)
    }
}
```

In Swift 3, I think I'm meant to do something like this...

```
func testAlertOperationPresentsMessage() {
    var testSuccess = false
    let action: AlertClosure = { action in
        testSuccess = true
    }

    let alert = AlertOperation(title: "Test", message: "Message", context: nil, action: action)

    let group = DispatchGroup()
    OperationQueue.main.async(group: group) { 
        alert.start()
    }
    group.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) { XCTAssert(testSuccess) }
}
```

or:

```
func testAlertOperationPresentsMessage() {
    var testSuccess = false
    let action: AlertClosure = { action in
        testSuccess = true
    }

    let alert = AlertOperation(title: "Test", message: "Message", context: nil, action: action)

    alert.completionBlock = { XCTAssert(testSuccess) }

    let queue = OperationQueue()
    queue.addOperation(alert)
    queue.waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished()
//    OperationQueue.main.addOperation(alert)

}
```

I use the following type alias:

```
typealias AlertClosure = ((UIAlertAction) -> Void)?
```

If needed I can include code for `AlertOperation`, but that doesn't seem necessary at this point. Essentially, the `AlertOperation` presents a message and then performs the `AlertClosure` when USER taps OK button.